# Code using {if} for genders - Need to add more

Tags: php

I'm working with a pre made theme using TPL and PHP. The original coder used:
"Male" "Female" & "Other" as his three sources of gender.

Everytime I try add "Trans Male" or "Trans Female" to the values, it says "Please pick a valid gender" when selecting Trans, even though I have added them into my database under the "User_Gender". I'm guessing you cannot use {If} as it exceeds three options?

I can't work out how I correctly code them into the {If} sequence or would I need to re-write the code to display and store the gender?

This is the code (for picking the gender on registration) (Also having problems when selecting it on registration too):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="gender">{__("I am")}</label>
  <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="none">{__("Select Sex")}:</option>
    <option {if $user_profile->gender == "male"}selected{/if} value="male">{__("Male")}</option>
    <option {if $user_profile->gender == "female"}selected{/if} value="female">{__("Female")}</option>
    <option value="other">{__("Other")}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I turned the code too:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="gender">{__("I am")}</label>
  <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="none">{__("Select Sex")}:</option>
    <option {if $user_profile->gender == "male"}selected{/if} value="male">{__("Male")}</option>
    <option {if $user_profile->gender == "female"}selected{/if} value="female">{__("Female")}</option>
    <option {if $user_profile->gender == "transmale"}selected{/if} value="transmale">{__("Trans Male")}</option>
    <option {if $user_profile->gender == "transfmale"}selected{/if} value="transfmale">{__("Trans Female")}</option>
    <option value="other">{__("Other")}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

"Please select valid gender" when I test the sign up. The Database values are:
"user_gender" "ENUM" "Values:'male','female','transmale','transfmale','other'"

Also does this when trying to pull the info from the database to store onto the user profile with fa fa icons. I adapted the code to match the output:

```
<li>
  <div class="about-list-item">
    {if $profile['user_gender'] == "male"}
      <i class="fa fa-male fa-fw fa-lg"></i>
      {__("Male")}
    {elseif $profile['user_gender'] == "female"}
      <i class="fa fa-female fa-fw fa-lg"></i>
      {__("Female")}
    {else}
      <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw fa-lg"></i>
      {__("Other")}
    {/if}
  </div>
</li>
```

Them three work fine. But, when I add trans into the equation it doesn't. Even if I place the trans options after the `{else}` tagged with other. Still gives me the please select valid gender.

Where am I going wrong? Or is the `{if}` string not suitable for this?

Comment: which tpl system you use?

Comment: Snginefrom CodeCanyon.  its tricky to add custom code to the .tmp files. >.<

Comment: The closest I got to it working was adding the genders after the {else} tag before other but then on profile it displays as "Trans Male Trans Female Other". I want them to be seperate but don't know the correct syntax to pull the info and store it. Is {if} the correct string for this?

Comment: try this , using ternary operator
<option {$user_profile->gender == 'male' ? 'selected' : ''} value="male">{__("Male")}</option>

Comment: I'll give this a go see if it works. Coding can be such a ache at times ^.^ Thank you, ill let you know if it registers. Is my MYSQL correct as far as storing the genders as ENUM?

Comment: Got a 500 error :(